# Can you have member variables in a python function

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm wondering if there's a way to have member variables in a function instance. For example,

```
incr_instance = incrementor(1)
incr_instance()
incr_instance()
incr_instance()
```

would print out

```
1
2
3
```

Yes, I know I can just use a class, but this is a question about weird language quirks in the python language.

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Can you clarify if x is the initial value or the step value?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a function `incrementor` that returns another function that keeps incrementing the counter `n` (the inner function uses `nonlocal n` to access `n` instead of using `incrementor.n`):

```
def incrementor(n):
  def inc():
    nonlocal n
    n += 1
    return n - 1
  return inc
```

Test:

```
incr_instance = incrementor(1)
incr_instance_2 = incrementor(10)

print(incr_instance())
print(incr_instance())
print(incr_instance())
print(incr_instance_2())
print(incr_instance_2())
print(incr_instance_2())
print(incr_instance())
print(incr_instance())
print(incr_instance())
print(incr_instance_2())
print(incr_instance_2())
print(incr_instance_2())
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
10
11
12
4
5
6
13
14
15
```

Comment: Same problem as the other answer, all your instances share the same static variable.+

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```py
def incrementor(n):
    def incrementor_aux():
        incrementor_aux.x += n
        print(incrementor_aux.x)
    incrementor_aux.x = 0
    return incrementor_aux
```

You can even create multiple incrementors and have them increment their values independantly:

```py
incr_instance1 = incrementor(1)
incr_instance2 = incrementor(1)
incr_instance1() #prints 1
incr_instance1() #prints 2
incr_instance2() #prints 1
incr_instance1() #prints 3
incr_instance2() #prints 2
```

What happens is a new instance of `incrementor_aux` function is created everytime you call `incrementor`, with its own `x` local value which stays in each instance's scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
def incrementor(i=0):
    def inc():
        inc.i += 1
        return inc.i
    inc.i = i - 1
    return inc

incr_inst = incrementor(1)  
incr_inst() # 1
incr_inst() # 2
```

But for this actual task

```
from itertools import count

incr = count(1)
incr() # 1
incr() # 2
```

Comment: Not bad but there are no function "instances" with this, there's only one global state (the function itself).

Comment: @alexis: Yep.  Misunderstood the question.  I'll just wrap this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a factory that gives you functions with local state, without using a class. Instead of making the state variable a member of the function, I'd use python's `nonlocal` syntax:

```
def incrementor(start):
    state = start -1
    def interior():
        nonlocal state
        state += 1
        return state
    return interior
```

This will print `7`, then `8`:

```
inc7 = incrementor(7)
print(inc7())
print(inc7())
```

This will print `1`, then `9 10`, then `2 3`; each of the functions `inc1()` and `inc7()` is going at its own pace.

```
inc1 = incrementor(1)
print(inc1())

# Yes, I can mix them

print("inc7 again:", inc7(), inc7())
print("inc1 again:", inc1(), inc1())
```

Comment: i think the OP explicitly asked for function member

Comment: The way I read it, the OP was describing the desired behavior, not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that doesn't use function attributes:

```
from functools import partial
def increment(x):
    def gen():
        y = x
        while True:
            y += 1
            yield y
    g = gen()
    return partial(next, g)

f1 = increment(1)
f1()
# 2
f1()
# 3
f2 = increment(0)
f2()
# 1
f2()
# 2
f1()
# 4
```

Comment: Your answer made me realize that the x argument could be the initial value or the step value

Comment: In either case it'd be trivial to implement either or both in our answers, but a good clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I fancied having a go at this and tried to make it concise, here's what I ended up with. It's not best practice but you asked for quirky!

*The aim here was to not pass the value back into the function, as the OP requested.*

```
index = 0;
incr_instance = lambda: [index, exec("global index; index += 1")]
print(incr_instance()[0])
print(incr_instance()[0])
print(incr_instance()[0])
```

Will print

```
0
1
2
```

Index is our global which keeps track of our progress, the lambda expression executes two statements. The first statement returns the value of index and the second increments it, which had to be done using exec as you cannot assign variables from a lambda as it's for expressions only. The two statements are within square brackets in order to run both; otherwise it will return index only.

The `[0]` index gives us the value of `index` rather than the result of the exec expression (always `None`)